# How to implement MUI skeleton on API response data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, shimmer

I am using [material-ui skeleton](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/) (Shimmer effect) on data which is coming from API.

```
{
accountData.usersAccountData.map((userData, index) => (
// ...UI code
)
)
}
```

Output is given below :
[image: output]
As you can see, I received 3 objects from API. So `accountData.usersAccountData.map` will run 3 times.
My question is, How can I implement `mui skeleton` while API is under process ?
How can show shimmer effect while API is under process ?

**NOTE :**
I have tried `<Skeleton ...otherParams />` inside `accountData.usersAccountData.map` but this didn't work because `accountData.usersAccountData` length is `zero` while API is under process.

Comment: Is your api has loading response at the time of api calling?

Comment: I am getting data from API when status code is 200.

Comment: In the duration of api calling and response receive are you maintaining any key for wait for response or you have only implemented condition for render your UI.

Comment: I am calling API from `redux action`. Whenever any API call, It will have three states : `API_REQUEST`, `API_SUCCESS`, `API_FAILURE`. Inside `API_REQUEST` I receive an object from redux `{isAPILoading : true}` and It will become `{isAPILoading : false}` in other two cases.

Comment: Yes, I can access `{isAPILoading : true/false}` inside my component. So when API is in under process I will receive `{isAPILoading : true}` and When I get response, I will receive `{isAPILoading : false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to implement isAPILoading for skeleton before your main UI render like this

```
if (isAPILoading) {
  return <Skeleton ...otherParams />;
}

return (
   {
     accountData.usersAccountData.map((userData, index) => (
    // ...UI code
    )
   )
  }
    )
```

but you need to also check for whether your response is success or fail if success you can show your UI else you can show error for the same.

Comment: Okay, thanks but, how do I know for how many rows skeleton should generate ? As currently I am receiving 3 objects. So we are seeing three UI rows.

Comment: `<Skeleton ...otherParams />` will generate a single row.

Comment: Skeleton basically we are using for just like a place holder so as per your need you can create a static rows count which looks better for your UI.

Comment: Okay then no issue.